# What are the crest colors and how much of it do I need for each stage?

Tags: league-of-legends

There are crests on the profile page. What colors are there and how much takedowns/kills/wins do I need for each stage of it? (This question is also for the dominion crests)

Images of the crests would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The colors range from none, to Bronze, Silver, Gold, then Platinum. What these count are the total number of Take-downs (which is a summary of your kills, assists, and destroyed towers), Monster/Minion Kills, and Wins in Classic, and Take-downs, Points Captured/Neutralized, and Wins in Dominion.

The thresholds are as follows:

[image: None]

None, this shows in your profile if you do not meet the minimum thresholds for Bronze.

[image: Bronze]
<sub>(source: [wikia.com](https://images.wikia.com/leagueoflegends/images/b/b4/BronzeBadgeSeason2.png))</sub>

### Bronze

**Classic**

- 100 Takedowns
- 2,000 Monster/Minion Kills
- 5 Wins

**Dominion**

- 100 Takedowns
- 100 Points captured/neutralized
- 5 Wins

**ARAM**

- 100 Takedowns
- 5 Towers Destroyed
- 5 Wins

[image: Silver]
<sub>(source: [wikia.com](https://images.wikia.com/leagueoflegends/images/9/99/SilverBageSeason2.png))</sub>

### Silver

**Classic**

- 1,000 Takedowns
- 10,000 Monster/Minion Kills
- 25 Wins

**Dominion**

- 500 Takedowns
- 250 Points captured/neutralized
- 25 Wins

**ARAM**

- 500 Takedowns
- 25 Towers Destroyed
- 25 Wins

[image: Gold]
<sub>(source: [wikia.com](https://images.wikia.com/leagueoflegends/images/7/77/GoldBadgeSeason2.png))</sub>

### Gold

**Classic**

- 2,500 Takedowns
- 50,000 Monster/Minion Kills
- 100 Wins

**Dominion**

- 2,500 Takedowns
- 500 Points captured/neutralized
- 100 Wins

**ARAM**

- 2,500 Takedowns
- 100 Towers Destroyed
- 100 Wins

[image: Platinum]
<sub>(source: [wikia.com](https://images.wikia.com/leagueoflegends/images/5/5f/PlatinumBadgeSeason2.png))</sub>

### Platinum

**Classic**

- 5,000 Takedowns
- 100,000 Monster/Minion Kills
- 300 Wins

**Dominion**

- 5,000 Takedowns
- 1,000 Points captured/neutralized
- 300 Wins

**ARAM**

- 5,000 Takedowns
- 200 Towers Destroyed
- 300 Wins (unconfirmed)

[image: Diamond]
<sub>(source: [wikia.com](https://images.wikia.com/leagueoflegends/images/0/03/DiamondBadge.png))</sub>

### Diamond

**Classic**

- 10,000 Takedowns
- 200,000 Monster/Minion Kills
- 600 Wins

**Dominion**

- 10,000 Takedowns
- 5,000 Points captured/neutralized
- 600 Wins

**ARAM**

- 10,000 Takedowns
- 500 Towers Destroyed (unconfirmed)
- 600 Wins

Sourced from the [LoL wiki](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Summoner_profile)

Comment: And for the other stats?

Comment: @Fredy31 I'm having difficulty finding verified thresholds for the other statistics, especially Dominion. I'm going to have to fiddle with the formatting here for the rest of the information.

Comment: It seems I must slay 7,000 more monsters! I'll get right on that!

Comment: @FAE Time to update this. There's now a "Diamond" tier, so I don't know if they increased the criteria for diamond, or if it just shortened the tier length or what.

Comment: Dominion win requirement for platinum is higher than 500